# AngularJS Image Source Change on Mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to get an icon to change on mouseover in AngularJS but am experiencing great difficulty. My menus are generated from JSON objects interpreted into HTML by Angular. Each menu item is its own object with its own title, link, icon, and alternative icon.

Currently my HTML is:

```
    <ul ng-controller="MenuCtrl" class="ul">
    <li class="profile-li" ng-repeat="item in profileItems" style="white-space:nowrap" width="250px">
        <div width="200px">
            <a href="{{item.link}}" class="return">
                <div ng-init="itemsrc='{{item.icon}}'" ng-mouseover="itemsrc='{{item.alticon}}'" ng-mouseout="itemsrc='{{item.icon}}'" >
                    <img class="icon2" ng-src="{{itemsrc}}"  style="display:inline; float:left;">
                    </img>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="{{item.link}}" class="return">
                <span style="display:inline; white-space:nowrap;"><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.profileItem}}</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>       
</ul>
```

Within a `<div>` `ng-init` sets the initial icon to a variable (`itemsrc`) equivalent to the icon path specified in the JSON object. `ng-mouseover` and `ng-mouseout` change this variable to different paths depending on the JSON values. The `<img>` within the `<div>` then uses this established variable as its `ng-src`.

When the page is loaded, the values in the `<div>` are generated appropriately (they show the correct paths stored in the JSON object), but the `<img src>` path is still shown in bracketed notation (`{{item.icon}}` or `{{item.alticon}}`), rather than an actual path (`icon/assessment.png` for example) which causes the image to break.

Here is a sample of the JSON object that is being interpreted:
`

```
[
  {
    "contentItem": "Orders",
    "link": "#orders",
    "icon": "icon/orders.png",
    "alticon": "icon/ordersb.png"
  },
  {
    "contentItem": "Medication Admin.", 
    "link": "#medAdmin",
    "icon": "icon/medicationAdmin.png",
    "alticon": "icon/medicationAdminb.png"
  },
  {
    "contentItem": "Lab Results", 
    "link": "#labs",
    "icon": "icon/labs.png",
    "alticon": "icon/labsb.png"
  },
  {
    "contentItem": "Vital Signs", 
    "link": "#vitals",
    "icon": "icon/vitals.png",
    "alticon": "icon/vitalsb.png"
  },
  {
    "contentItem": "Assessment", 
    "link": "#assessment",
    "icon": "icon/assessment.png",
    "alticon": "icon/assessmentb.png"
  },
    {
    "contentItem": "Intake & Output", 
    "link": "#io",
    "icon": "icon/intakeOutput.png",
    "alticon": "icon/intakeOutputb.png"
  }
]
```

Here's an example of what the HTML looks like in the browser:

```
<li class="profile-li ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in profileItems" style="white-space:nowrap" width="250px">
            <div width="200px">
                <a href="#face" class="return">
                    <div ng-init="itemsrc='icon/facesheet.png'" ng-mouseover="itemsrc='icon/facesheetb.png'" ng-mouseout="itemsrc='icon/facesheet.png'">
                        <img class="icon2" ng-src="{{item.icon}}" style="display:inline; float:left;" src="{{item.icon}}">

                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#face" class="return">
                    <span style="display:inline; white-space:nowrap;" class="ng-binding"><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;Face Sheet</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: `ng-mouseover` will evaluate the givin expression. When using quotes in this expression, you are actually passing a string `"{{item.altIcon}}"` which will not be parsed. Instead, try `ng-mouseover="itemsrc=item.alticon"` (same for ngMouseout and ngInit)

Comment: That introduces a different issue, results in this:
`<li class="profile-li ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in profileItems" style="white-space:nowrap" width="250px">
   <div width="200px">
    <a href="#face" class="return">
     <div ng-init="itemsrc=icon/facesheet.png" ng-mouseover="itemsrc=icon/facesheetb.png" ng-mouseout="itemsrc=icon/facesheet.png">
      <img class="icon2" style="display:inline; float:left;">
      
     </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#face" class="return">
     <span style="display:inline; white-space:nowrap;" class="ng-binding"><br>Face Sheet</span>
    </a>
   </div>
  </li>`

Comment: @floribon 
TL,DR: The image tag now has no `ng-src` or `src` attribute when the page loads (with method).

Comment: what are you writing in ng-src exactly, `{{item.icon}}` or `{{itemsrc}}` ? Also, do you hav any errors in your developper console?

Comment: I figured it out. In your initial suggestion, I removed the quotes but not the curly braces from `item.alticon`, etc. Once the curly braces were removed, it worked correctly. Thank you!

I get not using the quotations, but don't understand why the curly braces aren't needed. Is it because its within an angular expression?

Comment: @floribon also, if you post your comment as an answer I will mark it as such.

Comment: @P alright I should have done that from the beginning but I was feeling lazy. You have more details in my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As discussed by comments, the error was that you were using curly brackets in expression-bindings (more explanation about that at the end).

This will not work: (a)

```
ng-init="itemsrc = '{{item.icon}}'"
```

This will not work either: (b)

```
ng-init="itemsrc = {{item.icon}}"
```

This will: (c)

```
ng-init="itemsrc = item.icon"
```

> In case (a), the `itemSrc` variable will get the string value `"{{item.icon}}"` with no further processing, which is quite useless.
>
> The case (b) is a syntax error and will likely make angular report errors.

You need to understand that tere is not a unique way to pass information to a directive in Angular, but many:

- one way binding (`@`), which will assign a string to a variable. The string can contain curly brackets to be dynamic. For instance the `ng-src` attribute of an `<img>` tag, such as `<img ng-src="some/path/{{dynamicName}}.png">`
- two ways binding (`=`), where angular expect a variable and will keep a reference to it. For instance `ng-model` in an `<input>` tag: when modified by the input, the variable in ngModel will also be modified in the upper scope
- expression binding (`&`), for which angular expect an expression (a full snippet of code) that will be executed on a specific action. It is the case of `ng-init`, `ng-click` and the like. No curcly brackets, just a line of code that will be processed, such as `itemsrc = item.icon;` (you can have `;` here, it is code, but no `{{}}`)

Comment: Great answer. There is a small error in the syntax for (c), though. There is a rogue apostrophe.